How do I get Docker working again after taking MacOS Sonoma 14.6 update on M1 Pro?
Docker version 4.33.0
After taking the OS update over the weekend, I tried to open docker this morning, and it doesn't work. It said "Docker Engine stopped" and no real options to do anything. It is just stuck in limbo. Has anyone else ran across this and had any luck finding a solution?
We tried to uninstall and reinstall which now just gives an indefinite spinner saying "Starting the Docker Engine...". Nothing is working, I can't see the list of containers or add a new one.

What else have you tried? Have you looked into this GitHub issue and tried some of the solutions suggested there?
